# d3 make text in centre of donut clickable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a donut created using c3 and d3 - I have added some text to the centre of the donut using:

```
label.html('');
label.insert('tspan').text('4').attr('dy', -5).attr('x', 0).attr('class','h4');
label.insert('tspan').text('remaining').attr('dy', 20).attr('x', 0).attr('class','text-size-small');
```

This works fine but I would like the whole label text to be clickable - I can add html to the label but it creates a new link rather than making the current text clickable:

```
label.html('');
label.insert('tspan').text('4').attr('dy', -5).attr('x', 0).attr('class','h4');
label.insert('tspan').text('remaining').attr('dy', 20).attr('x', 0).attr('class','text-size-small').html('<a href="">link</a>');
```

I tried things like below but this does not display anything:

```
label.html('<a href="/">');
label.insert('tspan').text('4').attr('dy', -5).attr('x', 0).attr('class','h4');
label.insert('tspan').text('remaining').attr('dy', 20).attr('x', 0).attr('class','text-size-small').html('<a href="">link</a>');
label.html('</a>');
```

How can I make it so the whole label clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out to do this a slightly different way - there is a click event which can be used like below:

```
label.html('');
label.insert('tspan').text('4').attr('dy', -5).attr('x', 0).attr('class','h4 pointer').on("click", function() { window.open("https://www.google.com")});
label.insert('tspan').text('remaining').attr('dy', 20).attr('x', 0).attr('class','text-size-small pointer').on("click", function() { window.open("https://www.google.com")});
```

In this instance, I have also added a class called pointer so it is obvious the text is a link.

The specific part which was needed is:

```
.on("click", function() { window.open("https://www.google.com")});
```